# R: by grouping in datatable, get the first row and their corresponding row numbers for each group

Tags: r, datatable, group-by, grouping, symbols

I am wondering using `datatable`, how I can use the combination of `"special-symbols"` to get the **first row** and **their corresponding row numbers** (in the reference) in a data-set for each `group`?

**as example :**

```
Library(data.table)  
copy(mtcars) -> mt
setDT(mt) -> mt
```

get the first row of each group for `cyl`:

```
 mt[, .SD[1], by = cyl]

    cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

get the row number in mt corresponding to each group based on `cyl`:

```
mt[, .I[1], by = cyl]
   cyl V1
1:   6  1
2:   4  3
3:   8  5
```

**the expected output:**

```
    cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb   row_N
1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4    1
2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1    3
3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2    5
```

I tried the followings but was not successful:

```
mt[, .SD[1], by= cyl][mt[, .I[1], by=cyl]]
mt[, .SD[1], by= cyl][mt[, `:=` (row_N = .I[1], by=cyl)]]
```

any help with explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to combine the columns together with `cbind`.

```
mt[, cbind(.SD[1], row_N=.I[1]), by = cyl]
   cyl  mpg disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb row_N
1:   6 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4     1
2:   4 22.8  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1     3
3:   8 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2     5
```

Comment: Or just `c` instead of `cbind` since `c(list(1),2)` returns a list which will be translated to columns.